# Multiple named windows allowed in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Does PySpark support multiple named windows in the same query? I want to calculate moving averages of various sizes in the same query.

```
seconds_per_day = 86400
seconds_per_minute = 60
sql('''
    SELECT datetime,
           symbol,
           price,
           AVG (price) OVER past_7_days AS price_7_day_avg,
           AVG (price) OVER past_1_hour AS price_1_hour_avg
      FROM data_formatted
    WINDOW past_7_days AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
           ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
           RANGE BETWEEN 7 * {days} PRECEDING AND 1 * {minutes} PRECEDING)
    WINDOW past_1_hour AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
           ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
           RANGE BETWEEN 60 * {minutes} PRECEDING AND 1 * {minutes} PRECEDING)
     ORDER BY symbol ASC, datetime DESC
      '''.format(
        days=seconds_per_day,
        minutes=seconds_per_minute)).show(1)
```

However my code produces the following error:

```
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'ORDER' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'LIMIT'}(line 14, pos 5)

== SQL ==

    SELECT datetime,
           symbol,
           price,
           AVG (price) OVER past_7_days AS price_7_day_avg,
           AVG (price) OVER past_1_hour AS price_1_hour_avg
      FROM data_formatted
    WINDOW past_7_days AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
           ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
           RANGE BETWEEN 7 * 86400 PRECEDING AND 1 * 60 PRECEDING)
    WINDOW past_1_hour AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
           ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
           RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 60 PRECEDING AND 1 * 60 PRECEDING)
     ORDER BY symbol ASC, datetime DESC
-----^^^
```

Taking out the second named window (and the column that uses it) causes the code to run without errors, but I have to calculate lots of moving averages and I don't want to create a separate table for each column.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your SQL statement with just one WINDOW declaration and multiple named windows separated by comma (,) as follows and it should work.

```
SELECT datetime,
       symbol,
       price,
       AVG (price) OVER past_7_days AS price_7_day_avg,
       AVG (price) OVER past_1_hour AS price_1_hour_avg
  FROM data_formatted
WINDOW past_7_days AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
       ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
       RANGE BETWEEN 7 * {days} PRECEDING AND 1 * {minutes} PRECEDING),
       past_1_hour AS (PARTITION BY symbol 
       ORDER BY CAST(datetime AS long)
       RANGE BETWEEN 60 * {minutes} PRECEDING AND 1 * {minutes} PRECEDING)
 ORDER BY symbol ASC, datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I use several windows in the same query but I use them sql API and it works.